# Shared button component in TypeScript but event is not visible to all pages (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript, button, onclick

In Angular 5 there is shared button component which is used by two pages. 
page1 and page2. But click event is only visible to page1. Don't know if something I am missing here. 
Shown below is the full structure of component hierarchy.

```
Index.html
   App.html
      page1.html
            btn.html
      page2.html  
            btn.html
```

btn.html component is common for page1 and page2. 
Problem is on button click event of btn.component.ts is executed only on page1.html.
page2.html doesn't know about this event.

I have created this plunker code to show my problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ry5Uj2VHzVK0RfaJcXyZ?p=info

Please help me here. How can I fix this issue? Or what is wrong I am doing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the click event is binding only for the first instance of that component. so you can try this:

In btn-shared component html:

```
<div>
  <label>This is test button</label>
  <input type="button" id="Testbtn" value="Click me" (click)="FunctionOnClick()"> 
</div>
```

In btn-shared component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn-shared',
  templateUrl: 'src/shared/btn.component.html'
})
export class btnComponent {

public FunctionOnClick(){
  alert("Clicked ");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Prachi. It worked. I don't why I didn't try that. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: Hey Prachi, Now I remember why I didn't try that. Actually problem was not with calling function with click. I just simplified the problem. I wants to enable and disable the button based on some logic. So the problem is still there. :-(

Comment: You can create a isDisabled variable in btn-shared component and you can modify its value separately for both the components using ViewChild

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I figured it out. I am generating button ID at run time. Using that new ID I can enable OR Disable the button. But you really helped.